# Не получается поставить .box при вёрстке сайта

Tags: html, css

когда прописываю в html конструкцию

```
<div class="box"></div>,
```

а в css

```
.box {
width: 600;
height: 600;
background-color: green;
}
```

то на моём сайте ничего не получается. В чём моя ошибка?

[image: мой код html]

[image: мой css]

Comment: На сайте не появляется блока в принципе

Comment: Он как будто его не видит. Я и размер меняла, и проверила вроде все, но в коде прописано, а на сайте - пусто((

Comment: У width и height не указаны единицы измерения

Comment: Спасибо, святой человек! Удивительно, как я сама на это не обратила внимания... Не знаю, можно ли тут ставить лайки или давать +rep (первый раз на сайте). Но если можно, было бы признательна - если подскажите!!!

Comment: @DaryanaS, можно давать метку правильного ответа, если на ваш вопрос прислали ответ, а не комментарий, как в данном случае